# how to extract Message title and body form OneSignal push notifications Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, onesignal

guys, I am trying to get the Notification Title and Body from OneSignal push notifications I've tried to get the data from JSON like HTTP but it didn't works

```
OneSignal.shared
        .setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) {
      // will be called whenever a notification is received

      print('Recived Notification is : $notification');

      notification.convertToJsonString({'title': title, 'alert': body});

      print('Title is : $title');
      print('Description is : $body');
    });


onesignal( 9471): Created json raw payload: {vis=1, google.original_priority=normal, google.sent_time=1566080374593, pri=5, grp_msg=, google.delivered_priority=normal, custom={"i":"cb91f929-3008-4364-a687-1675448c2d0a"}, oth_chnl=, title=Welcom test Notification, google.message_id=0:1566080374598190%ab53bc02f9fd7ecd, alert=this is description of welcome text content notification, google.ttl=259200, from=613584415888, notificationId=173367476}
I/flutter ( 9471): Recived Notification is : Instance of 'OSNotification'
I/flutter ( 9471): Title is : null
I/flutter ( 9471): Description is : null
```

Answer (score 3):

I HAVE Fixed my problem  its simply  getting the payload of the notification like this

```
OneSignal.shared
      .setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) {
    // will be called whenever a notification is received

    print('Recived Notification is : $notification');

    title = notification.payload.title;
    body = notification.payload.body;
  });
```

and here is reference of the solution from [OneSignal Docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk#section--osnotificationpayload-)

Answer (score 0):

For onesignal_flutter package version: 5.0.4

```
 OneSignal.Notifications.addClickListener((event) {
      print("all events: $event");
      print("body is: ${event.notification.additionalData}");
    });
```